# Opera Workspaces for Firefox

Tags: firefox, opera

I like using Opera but I want to replace it with Firefox because it is open-source and more reliable (also a little bit faster for Ubuntu I think). However, I really love the Opera's Workspaces feature. It helps me to group my tabs with respect to subjects. Is there any add-on or something like that for Firefox that adds workspaces like in Opera? Thanks.

Comment: If you don't insist on "workspaces" specifically, other methods to organize tabs may be worth a look. I personally like [Tree Style Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/tree-style-tab/), which gives you a sidebar with a tree of your tabs. You can organize tabs into multiple sub-trees, collapse and expand sub-trees etc. Also, there are "tab groups" like (arbitrarily chosen) [Simple Tab Groups](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/simple-tab-groups/). But I've found it too easy to forget about the tabs I had "hidden away", so I like them to stay visible in the tree.

Comment: Oh, actually when I think of it tree style tabbing may be much more efficient than "workspaces". I hope it is not over-complicated. I will definitely give it a try. Thanks :)

Comment: I just extended my comment to answer, to better stay within the concept of the site :)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't insist on the workspace context specifically, there are Add-ons for Firefox that offer other methods to organize tabs.

One of them is [Tree Style Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/tree-style-tab/). This Add-on offers a sidebar with a tree of your tabs. In that tree, you can organize your tabs in different sub trees, for example one sub tree per topic. The sidebar is offered in addition to Firefox' standard tab bar. You can hide the standard tab bar in your `userChrome.css` file (Add-ons don't have access to those things, so TST can't do that itself). But there are [some disadvantages](https://github.com/piroor/treestyletab/wiki/Code-snippets-for-custom-style-rules#for-userchromecss) of this solution, so use it at your discretion. Additionally, there are [a number of additional Add-ons](https://github.com/piroor/treestyletab#addons-that-extend-tst) that extend TST, so you can customize the functionality more.

Another concept are "tab groups". Some years ago, tab groups were quite a big thing in Firefox. But with the change to the WebExtension format for Add-ons the things that Add-ons can do have been stripped down quite a bit, so many tab group Add-ons can't offer the same functionality they used to offer. Nevertheless, there are still some around, like (arbitrarily chosen) [Simple Tab Groups](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/simple-tab-groups/). Those may be worth a look as well. But I personally found it too easy to forget about the tabs I "hid away" in groups, so I like to keep them visible in TST's tree.

Answer (score 0):

There is an add-on for Firefox called Workspaces.

[image]

In your Firefox Browser go to [this link](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/workspaces-for-firefox/)

Comment: Thanks. I have used this addon but I found it quite ugly for some reason. I will give it a second chance tomorrow and edit this comment.